# can not import Excel files to my site

Tags: c#-4.0

I make a website using asp.net c#
On-site access to data from Excel file
my website  on my computer works without errors
And on the website server and when I set Excel file Please click on the button lift gives me the following error

> "The 'Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."

my conection string is :

```
OleDbConnection oldbcon = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=NO;IMEX =1 ;ImpoertMixedtypes = text;typeGuessRows = 0'");
```

Comment: Thank Konrad Krakowiak to re-coordinate Question

Comment: No one knows the solution to the problem !!!!!

Comment: It's not a problem at all. Obviously, your computer has Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB provider (it is installed with Microsoft Office usually, but can be also installed separately), but your werbserver doesn't has it. So just download it and install in your webserver.